# Intuition for Proving if a Set is Dense

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm having trouble building intuition for whether or not a set is dense in another set. I've read [this reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514999/intuition-for-dense-sets-real-analysis), which was helpful, but I'm having a few outstanding questions.

The examples provided in the link are obvious, and they don't really give me a good sense of how I would go about writing proofs or dis-proofs of denseness.

For example, I was posed the following two problems that, just looking at the provided reference, I don't have a clue how to tackle:

Are the following sets dense in $[0, 1]$?

- $\{\sin n \,| \,n \in \Bbb{N}\}$
- $\{frac(\pi^n) \,| \,n \in \Bbb{N}\}$

Where $frac$ is the fractional part of a number.

Are there any (better) references out there that can help me better understand not only what denseness *is*, but also how I should start proofs of this type?

Comment: One good way to think about dense sets is via limits or neighborhoods. A Set $A$ is dense in $[0,1]$ if any interval containing $x \in [0,1]$ contains also a point in $A$. We can then formulate this using epsilon language. Via sequences, one should be able to have a sequence in $A$ converging to any point in $[0,1]$.

Comment: To add to my comment since I can't figure out how to edit on my phone, think about how $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. No matter how small of an interval you take surrounding a real number, you can be sure that your interval is going to contain a rational number as well.

Comment: But that's my confusion. It's really easy to think about the set $\Bbb{Q}$, but I don't really know what the sets in my original post look like. Yeah, they're a bunch of non-terminating real numbers, and maybe I'll even concede that it makes *sense* that it should be dense in $[0, 1]$, but I don't know how to think about these specific sets in terms of neighborhoods.

Comment: If it is not yet clear, the issue does not seem to be your understanding of what dense means, but rather it seems to be a case of your examples being particularly difficult (without the right tools from *other areas* of mathematics). For example, someone can have a very good understanding of what an irrational number is and still not be able to prove that ${\pi}^5 - 8{\pi}^3$ is irrational.

Comment: $\{\sin(n) : n\in\mathbb N\}$ might be dense in $[-1,1]$, but not in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Take a point $x \in [0,1]$. For any $\epsilon>0$, can you find $n\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $|x-\sin(n)|<\epsilon$? Think about how $\sin{n}$ would distribute itself around a unit circle. Shouldn't we be able to find some interval where this can't be?

Comment: I think I'm missing something big here. Wouldn't a set being dense in $[-1, 1]$ imply that the set is dense in any of the subsets, namely $[0, 1]$? Also, to DaveNine's comment, $\sin n$ *feels* like it should cover the whole unit circle eventually, right? Two points can never overlap because integers can never differ by any multiple of $2\pi$, so it feels like we *can* find   $n$. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: You question about $\text{frac}(π^n)$ could be difficult : see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/102048) or [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002832).

Answer (score 1):

For sets of this type is well to remember the Equidistribution Theorem : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem . Morever you should note that the functions sine and $ frac $ are continuos and surjective in $[0,1)$ . In fact , if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuos and surjective ($X, Y$ are topological spaces) and $T\subset X$ is dense, then $f (T)$ is dense in $ Y $.

Comment: Wait, but the equidistribution theorem doesn't help with the sequence $\pi^n$.  And in what sense is frac continuous?  You should probably be a little more explicit about what map you are using to represent $\sin$.

Comment: And how can one get from $\{n\pi\mod 1: n\in\mathbb N\}$ (dense in $[0,1]$) to proving that $\{n\mod\pi : n\in\mathbb N\}$ is dense in $[0,\pi]$?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp There's no easy way between those two sets directly, but you can get from "$\{n/\pi\mod 1: n\in\mathbb N\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$" to "$\{n\mod\pi : n\in\mathbb N\}$ is dense in $[0,\pi]$" by composing with the homeomorphism $f(x)=\pi x$ from $[0,1]$ to $[0,\pi]$, which maps dense sets to dense sets.